# How can I move keyframes to specific frames with Python?

Tags: python, actions

I got animations/actions with a lot of frames, and I want to reduce it to animations/actions of 8 frames. I deleted a lot of keyframes, and now I have the result in the picture below. An action with a lot of frames empty. [image: Example of result of script]

I can't find a way to go from this to frame 1 to 8 filled with these keyframes (my terms might be a bit off, pretty new to this). I tried it with this bit of code:

```
x = 0
fr = 1
for frame in range(7):
     x += 1
     fr += 1
     #framesKeepList is a list of the frames that are kept. The filled frames that you can see in the picture above. 
     #in this case: [1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22]
     bpy.ops.action.select_column(framesKeepList[x])
                
     bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].frame_set(fr)
                
     bpy.ops.action.snap()
                
     bpy.ops.action.select_all(action="DESELECT")
```

This gives me the result in the picture below. Just one frame filled, the last frame. I have also had cases where it only did the second frame, where it looked like the DESELECT line made it so it wasn't able to do the other frames anymore.

[image: End result of second bit of code]

If anyone has any tips or knows a solution to this problem, I appreciate it.

Comment: Do you need to do this with python? You can select the key frames, and then press S to scale them about the time cursor.

Comment: @TheLabCat Ye, I'm doing this for hundreds of models, which each have around 20 actions. So I'm trying to automate it.

Comment: The code is a bit inefficient with variables (fr is just X plus 1 and X is in turn “frame” provided by the for loop), but looks functional. The question is wether framesKeepList is correct, and what bpy.ops.action.snap() does. I’ll look it up in the python docs, but I suspect that’s the line that’s moving all the key frames to the time cursor.

Comment: As suspected: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.action.html#bpy.ops.action.snap Remove that call to action.snap() and see if the code works.

Comment: Then nothing changes. I use the snap function for the actual moving of the keyframes. I printed framesKeepList in the console, and also with the counter, and that works properly.

Edit: Frame_set just moves the selection of the frame, not the actual selected column data to that frame. The thing I think is the problem is that when I select stuff, I can't deselect it. And when I use this deselection method it deselects too much, and it doesn't do anything for the action anymore.

Comment: Ahh, excuse me.

Answer (score 0):

First rule of Blender scripting: Don't use bpy.ops if at all possible.

Try to manipulate the actual data directly before you try to simulate stuff like "select, move, deselect etc". It's always cleaner and easier to work with.

I can't tell exactly your problem from your post, but this is how you move keyframes to specific locations.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.active_object

#fcurves is where object animation data like keyframes are stored
curves = obj.animation_data.action.fcurves

# loop over all the fcurves
for c in curves:
    # each curve has a keyframe_points attribute, thats where we can get the
    # keyframe_point.co attribute (coordinates)
    kfs = c.keyframe_points
    # use the enumerate keyword to get an index for free along with the iterable
    # you are already looping over.
    for i, kf in enumerate(kfs):
        # so every loop looks like
        # i = 0, kf = keyframe1
        # then
        # i = 1, kf = keyframe2
        # etc.
        
        # kf.co.x is the location in time, e.g what frame, kf.co.y would be the
        # 'magnitude' of the keyframe. All we need is to change the x axis.
        kf.co.x = i + 1
```

In action:

[image]

Comment: Trying to use this for my solution. But would you know a way to get this to work so you don't move them all to one frame (so not just 140 as input. But in your example, that you move the action data on frame 79 to the second frame, the data on frame 195 to the third frame, and so on?

Comment: Not exactly sure, but it sounds like you want to use the enumerate keyword. I edited my answer to show you.

Answer (score 0):

Worth adding to [Jakemoyo's comment](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271186/172086) that `kf.co.x` will not update the bezier handles of a key if any; instead, you have to use `kf.co_ui.x`.